# Hyperledger fabric behave tests failing "cannot connect to Docker endpoint"

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

Using Hyperledger fabric, I run `make behave-deps` then `make behave`, yet several of the behave test scenarios fail ("Error starting container: cannot connect to Docker endpoint") - how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running the vagrant-based development environment described [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devenv.md), a change was recently made to the Docker port mapping that would manifest itself with these failed tests. Reconstruct your development environment with `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` from the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/devenv` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this problem is encountered when  running outside of Vagrant.

Ensure you can run

> docker run hello-world

Without sudo

If this fails,  this can be resolved by adding he user to the group as in [the installation docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group)